# Why could the creatures in the Quiet Place hear the faintest sound from a large distance but couldn't spot a person a few feet from them?

Tags: a-quiet-place

In the Quiet Place movie, monster creatures roam the Earth searching for biological life that makes a sound. They seem to be able to pick up the least insignificant noise from a huge distance (such as a gas lamp toppling over inside a house), however they have a hard time spotting a person within the same room if they stay quiet enough.

Was there any explanation for this within the movie?

Answer (score 8):

There is a whiteboard shown at an early point in the film which provides convenient exposition.

[image]

> The monsters are blind.

Answer (score 7):

It's not explicitly mentioned in the film, but I think their ability to hear over such great distance actually is the reason they have trouble finding a relatively quiet person right in from of them.  There's the argument that people make noises all the time--breathing, heart beats, etc--but it surely would be difficult to pick out those sounds when you're also hearing the wind through the corn field outside or the squeaking of a floorboard next door.  At a certain point, acuity crossed over into hypersensitivity.

Comment: I agree, and I believe the film provides evidence to support this. Whenever the creatures are trying to locate something close up, we see them undergo a physical change. It does appear that listening for something near requires greater effort than hearing something far away.

Comment: It's the same reason as why the waterfall is safe.  The creatures are sensitive to sounds in excess of the ambient noise level.  Yes people breathe and their hearts beat, but in most places these sounds would be below the ambient background noise.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why they can hear a gas lamp topple over but can't hear people walking from a distance. This movie is wholly inconsistent.

Comment: @Charleh The people in the movie take great pains to walk silently

Comment: @forresthopkinsa they do, but there are wholly inconsistent levels of noise that alert them throughout. There is no way that the loudest sound level in the region at any time is the noise of them toppling a gas lamp, and it makes no sense that the sound would travel far enough to alert the monsters unless they were already close by, in which case they should have heard other things given how sensitive their hearing is supposed to be. It's a movie and it takes great liberties at bending the rules of physics/sound to keep the plot moving; it was overhyped too and this ruined it for me.

Comment: If you want to get technical - sound is energy that radiates from essentially a point source. Since there's a finite amount of energy that creates sound, and the sound radiates equally in all directions, it's subject to fall off following the inverse square law. This means as you get further from the source the sound starts to drop off more and more. At a certain point, the sound waves drop off enough to be the same number of decibels as the ambient background noise - it's not a question of how sensitive your hearing is, it's just a question of signal to noise ratio.

Comment: Given that normal conversation is about 65dBA - sound drops off 6dBA for the first meter, and then for every doubling of distance drops off another 6dBA. The ambient background noise level of a forest is anything from 15-20dBA for a very light 1m breeze, so if you do the math: at 128m, 65dBA has dropped to 23dBA - that's barely above the background noise of the forest. No matter how good the creatures can hear, if they are over 100m-150m away they can't hear you talk in the *open* let alone inside the walls of a cabin/house because there's no differentiating the sound from background noise.